# Rotate a Polygon node in Shader Graph

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I have a hexagon in the Polygon node I would like to rotate so the pointy side is upwards. Applying the rotation nodes, however, simply changes the color of the hexagon from white to a color in the rainbow.

What does the `Vector1` of the Polygon output represent and is there a way I can rotate it as if it were a texture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What does the Vector1 of the Polygon output represent

It represents whether the current pixel being shaded is inside (1) or outside (0) the polygon.

> and is there a way I can rotate it as if it were a texture?

Just like with a texture, you don't rotate the colour value coming *out* of the node. You have to rotate the sample coordinates going *into* the node.

Here's one way to do it, putting a Rotate node between UV0 and the Polygon node:

[image: Rotating the UVs]

Or you can just swap the X and Y axes of your input coordinate:

[image: Swizzling X & Y]